# The hash function used by new_trie_op

Tags: tex-core, hyphenation, knuth, web

In §**944** of *TeX, The Program* (Volume B of *Computers & Typesetting*) DEK describes the hash function used by *new_trie_op* in order to store hyphenation tables efficiently.
Quoting him:

> The hash function used by *new_trie_op* is based on the observation that
> 313/510 is an approximation to the golden ratio [cf. *The Art of
> Computer Programming* **3** (1973), 510–512]; *trie_op_hash_size* is usually
> a multiple of 510.

My question is: can it be a coincidence that DEK discusses the 313/510 ratio and the fact that *trie_op_hash_size* is a multiple of 510 giving as a reference page 510 of his *Art of the Computer Programming*?

Comment: There's a lot I don't understand here. (1) The current version of the program doesn't include this line, though I see it in [patgen](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/stanford/patgen/patgen.web) ([PDF](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/knuth-pdf/other/patgen.pdf)) (or [here](https://www.saildart.org/TEXHYF.WEB[TEX,DEK])) (2) The golden ratio is usually (1+√5)/2≈1.618, while 313/510≈0.6137, so it's actually closer to the reciprocal of the golden ratio. (3) Even then, neither 313/510 nor 510/313 is particularly close (315/510 would be closer), (4) If one wanted a prime then still 317/510 is closer, …

Comment: (5) There's in fact no `trie_op_hash_size` now, though there's `trie_op_size` that's set to 500 (6) Likely the page numbers are different in the current second edition (1998) of Volume 3 (7) All that said, I can't see (but that's not saying anything) any other rationale for choosing multiples of 510 so the coincidence may well have been intentional!\

Answer (score 2):

Of course, only Knuth himself can answer such a question. Here is my
comment.

You cite an old §944 that was replaced when \TeX\ became aware of
8-bit, several languages, and more; see tex82.bug.

*trie_op_hash_size* is twice (*max_quarterword*-*min_quarterword*) (§943) and
that is by default 2*255=510. In the procedure of section 944 a hash
function is used. The hash value is a summation of hash functions as
there are several keys; 313 and 361 are used as multiplier that are
relatively prime to 510. The factor 313 is used with the key for what
TeX calls the 'hyphen distance' in a pattern, usually a small
number. *Fibonacci hashing* is a good choice to spread the sequence
1,2,3,... but there are many entries with the same key so a summation of
several hash functions with other keys is used.

Nowadays the summation is still there extended by one summand that has
the multiplier 1009 for the current language. And now the computation
isn't done modulo 510 but modulo 2 times *trie_op_size* and the
reference disappeared; *trie_op_size* has the default value 500 not 255.

The text that starts on page 510 in TAOCP Vol. 3, first edition, 2nd
printing, starts in the second edition with Fig. 37 on page
517. Knuth looks at $\phi^{-1} = (\sqrt5 - 1)/2$ and calls it *golden
ratio*. The text describes the properties of Fibonacci hashing so the
reference to page 510 makes sense. BTW, the theory that is developed
there shows that an exact approximation is not necessarily the best in
certain situations, that is, 313 might be better than 317, although I
don't think it matters here. And note, the summation of hash functions
for several keys isn't mentioned in the old Vol. 3, the new edition
cites a paper from 1977.

But, well, you omit the last sentence of the cited paragraph in the
old §944: ``But the choice is comparatively unimportant in this
particular application.'' I think the reference to TAOCP is not
absolutely necessary to understand or explain the code and the
multiplier 313; maybe in 1982 it was and I have a modern view. It isn't nonsense as the reference points to hashing
but one can speculate that Knuth made the reference only because of
the stated coincidence. As soon as 510 was replaced the reference
disappeared (long before the 2nd edition of Vol. 3 was prepared). For
example, the section §920 kept its reference to the old Vol. 3.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR A quarterword has 8 bits, so max_quarterword is 255 and
min_quarterword 0 by default. The hash table should be able to store
max_quaterword entries but a hash table shouldn't have a high load
factor and the simplest thing is to use a table twice as large as
needed. The load factor is max. 0.5 and the average search times are
low. Of course, clustering should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: Oops, sorry about my previous comment; I vaguely recollected an off-by-one issue, but in writing it from memory I introduced a different off-by-one error of my own. Deleted the comment now as it would only add to the confusion. Anyway, the issue I had in mind is the following. You're right, by default min_quarterword is 0 and max_quarterword is 255. But this means there are actually (max_quarterword-min_quarterword+1)=256 possible entries, not (max_quarterword-min_quarterword)=255. Doubling 256 would have given 512 instead of 2*255=510. Thanks though; obviously there's only so much we can say!